# angular 2 bootstrap carousel as background

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

trying to do carousel and put pictures as background, hope someone can help me with that, sorry for my broken english :) 
Here code that i type :
First angular :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgStyle } from '@angular/common';
import { NgFor } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.css']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  images = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.images = [
  {"id":1, "url":"assets/img/header.jpeg"},
  {"id":2, "url":"assets/img/velo2.jpeg"},
  {"id":3, "url":"assets/img/velo3.jpeg"},
    ]
  }
}
```

and my html code:

```
<carousel >
  <slide *ngFor = "let image of images" >
    <div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': url(' + image.url + ')}"></div>
  </slide>

</carousel>
```

And here my errors:

```
ERROR TypeError: _co.url is not a function
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/SliderComponent.ngfactory.js:17)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (vendor.bundle.js:82907)
at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:82087)
at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:82452)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (vendor.bundle.js:82410)
at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:82088)
at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:82452)
at execComponentViewsAction (vendor.bundle.js:82384)
at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:82093)
at callViewAction (vendor.bundle.js:82452)
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: i get many errors :  and i dont get img as background :                    TypeError: _co.url is not a function

Comment: You should include them in the question.

Comment: ok, its done ))

Comment: Looks quite straight forward to me, `ERROR TypeError: _co.url is not a function`. Have you included all libraries that you need?

Comment: if i set it like usual carousel it works, so i include bootstrap, ngstyle and ngfor, whats libraries i should include ?